# Запутался по front-end разработке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Вопрос будет большим и очень запутанным, изучаю front-end разработку а именно техн. стэк (`Html,Css,Js,Jquery,React,Node.js`). Я сам бэк-энд(Spring) и Андроид-разработчик.Запутался в стэкэ а именно :

**1 ) Существует ли React вне nodeJs?**
Хотел изучить React но все что я нашел это то что я должен обязательно установить node сервер.А если я хочу использовать react для статического сайта который не взаимодействует с сервером.Неужели нельзя реакт использовать как . jQuery ?

**2 ) Что за архитектура в веб разработке?**

Почему не используется сервис на которые идёт запрос и откуда получается ответ, а тут  сразу на сайт  пвиливается nodeJs и оттудаже доступ к Бд , ведь если для телефона будет писаться клиент все-равно нужен будет сервис ,почему он на прямую подключаются без сервисов ?

Comment: 1) Да, вы запутались. «node сервер» нафиг не нужен, нужен просто nodejs, который запустит какой-нибудь сборщик (webpack?), который соберёт вам js-бандл, который вы статически раздадите на своём статическом сайте

Comment: 2) «Почему не используется сервис» — вообще-то используется и называется «node сервер» :) Но вас никто не заставляет писать сервер на node, можете использовать старый добрый php. Или python. Или perl. Или go

Comment: И да, «node сервер» принципиально ничем не отличается от «php сервера», «python сервера», «perl сервера» или «go сервера». Клиент для телефона неизбежно будет к чему-то подключаться, и этим чем-то может быть как «php сервер», так и «node сервер» — вас никто не ограничивает в выборе

Comment: Что такое «напрямую без сервисов?»

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы все не правильно поняли

> Хотел изучить React но все что я нашел это то что я должен обязательно установить node сервер

Это не совсем так, `nodejs` нужен, но не обязательно. `React` использует `jsx` для описания верстки компонентов, это почти как `html`, но со своими приблудами, которые обычный браузер не понимает. Поэтому в первую очередь код `React-компонента` нужно преобразовать. За этим и нужен `nodejs`, он используется в качестве инструмента, который на вход получает `jsx`, а на выходе отдает валидный `js`. Пример `jxs`:

```
<div>Hello, {user}</div>
```

Но вы так же можете писать `React-компоненты` и на чистом `js`, используя `helper-ы` ( который по сути используются для расшифровки `jsx` ). Без `jsx`:

```
// может сейчас чуть по другому, но суть та же
React.createElement('div', null, 'Hello, world')
```

*Зачем это нужно?*

Все дело в том, что сам парсер `jsx` весит `N` байт, которые пользователю не очень то и нужны, поэтому у вас встает выбор, либо вы делаете всю работу на клиенте ( загружаете туда парсер `jsx`, парсите им ваш код, и только потом собираете приложение )

Либо же, вы делаете это все на сервере, во время разработки, а клиенту отдаете только готовые минифицированные данные

> Почему не используется сервис на которые идёт запрос и откуда получается ответ, а тут сразу на сайт пвиливается nodeJs и от туда же доступ к Бд

Не понятно откуда вы это взяли, но `nodejs` не попадает клиенту в браузер. Может работать как сервер или вы имели в виду `ssr`? Ну, так это просто механизм преждевременной "компиляции" вашего приложения. То есть кроме того, что бы транспилировать (`jsx` > `js` ) ваш `react-код`, `nodejs` еще и выполнит первоначальный рендерениг всего приложения ( по умолчанию это делает браузер ). Тем самым клиенту отдастся уже готовый `html`, который отрисуется быстрее, чем если бы рендеринг происходил в браузере

Comment: запрос с reactJs идет в Node ?

Comment: @elik куда отправите, туда и идет. `React` - это библиотека компонентов, как вы реализуете работу с сервером и на чем написан сервер `React-у` совсем не важно